# add existing code directories to Visual C# 2010 express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

New to Visual C#. I can add existing .cs files but is there a way to add entire code directories to C#. Otherwise I would have to create folders again within visual C# and add files into it. There has to be an easier way to replicate my existing directory structure in visual C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Show All Files in Solution Explorer to see the entire filesystem within your project directory.

You can then right-click an entire folder (or select multiple folders) and click Include in Project.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply drag/drop folders from an explorer window into your solution by dropping them on the project or a sub-folder.